# get coordinates without gps (android)

Tags: android, mobile, gps

I'm developing a android app and I want to receive coordinates from a smartphone. Two questions:

1: GPS is enabled, but there is no signal, so I have no coordinates. How can I check, if GPS is sending coordinates or not?

2: If GPS is enabled and there is no signal, which other method can I use to get the coordinates from the smartphone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Getting coordinates requires using the location services, which by default uses all manner to determine location, not just the GPS, but cellular signals as well.  Here is a [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/) on using the location services in Android.

One word of advice - if you are going to use GPS and generally distribute your app, know that the GPS service is VERY battery intensive.  It requires judicious coding to not drain your users battery.  You have been warned!

Comment: Your tutorial shows how to use GPS, but if I get no coordinates from GPS, how can I get the coordinates?

Comment: @Sebastian  The tutorial DOES cover all services - in particular look for `LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER` in the tutorial.  That particular bit of code uses the cellular networks to determine location.  It's NOT as accurate as GPS, but it's close.

Comment: One note, if you are using Wi-Fi only device, then you will have to subscribe to a third party service to achieve your goal.  Location determination requires knowing where you are relative to fixed known locations if you don't have GPS.  The mobile networks know where their towers are.  If you are not using one of these two, then you will need another party that has those fixed locations.

Comment: I've tested your tutorial but I get this error: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class xxx.LocActivity; no empty constructor

Comment: OK but I will open a new question

Comment: @Sebastian  Great.  FYI, that's not my tutorial.  It's well done, but I cannot claim the credit.

Answer (score -2):

1) fetch device coordinates using locationService.

```
mContext = getActivity();
mLocationManager = (LocationManager)  mContext.getSystemService(Application.LOCATION_SERVICE);
mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(mProvider, 60000, 100, mAttLocationListener);
boolean gpsEnabled = mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(mProvider);
```

2) You can still get rough estimates using location information stashed in wi-fi